# Bootstrap fit child content and let other child scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div container with two columns, what I want is that container height fits the content of the left column, while right column scrolls in case of overflow. In particular, given the following html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div id="left-col" class="col-4">...</div>
      <div id="right-col" class="col-8">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want height of `.row` div fit `#left-col` content, while content of `#right-col` scrolls on overflow.
Can anyone achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may help you.

```css
  #right-col{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
   
<div class="container">
   <div class="row position-relative">
      <div id="left-col" class="col-4">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
      </div>
      <div id="right-col" class="col-8">
      What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point like).

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that greatly solves my problem. Meanwhile I found another solution that is setting right-col height from js equal to left-col height. But I prefer yours!

Comment: Hello @mcelia I am really very happy to help you.